# Starting a spring cloud service when consul is not available

Tags: spring-cloud

We have a number of services that are using consul for discovery.  We recently switched from Eureka.

If consul is not running then the services fail to start.  It is possible to use a similar mechanism that the consul config uses for failFast so it does not fail to start.

So basically, if consul is not available then it logs an error and continues.  Mostly this is for unit testing concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/175) to support `failFast=false` for discovery and you can disable consul discovery entirely for testing `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled=false` or put `@EnableDiscoveryClient` on a configuration class that is controled by a profile.